# Is there any appropriate idiom for the expression " its proved" or " its established"?

Tags: expressions, idioms, vocabulary

Is there any appropriate idiom for the expression " its proved" or " its established" ? For example, its proved and established he's not a good person.

Comment: Not exactly the same as "it's proved/proven" or "it's established" but you could say "There's no shadow of a doubt he's not ....", "It's clear-cut he's not ...", "There's no two ways about it, he's not...", As sure as eggs is eggs, he's not ...",

Comment: I have heard (usually from *Irish* speakers, I think) the form *[That's as] **Sure as the Pope's a Catholic**!* as an alternative to rhetorical *Is the Pope a Catholic?* (facetious version of emphatic agreement). But I don't think I've ever heard *Do bears shit in the woods?* recast to the corresponding sequence ***Sure as bears shit in the woods**!*

Comment: *It is known...*

Comment: Q.E.D. ("*quod erat demonstrandum*":"thus it has been demonstrated.") is likely too snooty for your intended use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D. Still, it'll work in a pinch.

Comment: It's well known that...   Everyone knows that...  Everyone who hasn't been living under a rock knows that...  The whole town knows that...

Answer (score 1):

You could say,

> He’s not a good person, and ***you can take that to the bank.***

> [YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/take-it-to-the-bank):
>
>   (idiomatic) Said to emphasize that something is known for sure.
>
> [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/can+take+it+to+the+bank):
>
>   Can believe a particular statement or piece of information
>     because it is definitely true (at least according to the speaker).
>   *I heard from a very reliable source
>     that this company is about to close—you can take it to the bank.*
>
> [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=take%20it%20to%20the%20bank):
>
>   Figurative: “What was said is the absolute truth
>     and can be verified by a third party source.” 
>     Comes from an obscure reference to cheques (or checks, if you're American),
>     in that such is a guarantee that you can take the document to the bank
>     and redeem it for its face value.
>
> [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_to_the_bank):
>
>   (transitive, idiomatic) To utterly trust, believe, or rely on.